# xunit.runner.visualstudio not working on Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

I got the following constellation:

Machine 1: 
- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.
- XUnit Test Runner installed via "Tools" / "Extensions"

Machine 2:
- Windows Server 2012 (Hyper V Virtual Box)
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

I've loaded a project, which I've created on Machine 1, on Machine 2. The project already contained Unit Tests which ran perfectly on Machine 1.

The installation of the XUnit Testrunner via "Tools" / "Extensions" got unavailable recently. Therefore I installed the package xunit.runner.visualstudio as a Nuget Package into my solution on machine 2. After I rebuilt my solution on machine 2 not tests are visible in Visual Studio on the newly setup box. What do I have to do to get my unit and integration tests back into the test runner? Is there anything else I need to install?

Thanks a lot for all your help