# Does xunit.runner.visualstudio not work for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I've done a nuget install like this:

```
Install-Package xunit.runner.visualstudio -Version 2.2.0
```

On my test project.

I have a test similar to this:

```
public class When_Doing_Stuff_I_Want_To_Test
{

    [Fact]
    public void Can_Do_Stuff()
    {
        var result = DoStuff();

        result.ShouldNotBeNull();
        result.Success.ShouldBeTrue();
    }
}
```

Although that I have done numerous VS restarts, laptop reboots, left a day in between, VS 2017 is still not able to discover my tests:[image]

> What can I do to fix this and see my tests?

**Addendum**

I'm working under 4.6.1, so not yet Core.

*Questions regarding the same topic that did not help:*

- [why-is-the-xunit-runner-not-finding-my-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214684/why-is-the-xunit-runner-not-finding-my-tests)
- [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647789/unit-tests-appear-in-xunit-gui-xunit-gui-clr4-exe-but-not-vs-2012-test-explore/16657414#comment23976438_16657414)
- [and this similar one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103781/why-is-the-visual-studio-2015-test-runner-not-discovering-my-xunit-v2-tests/35103782#35103782)
- [xunit.runner.visualstudio not working on Visual Studio 2013 Update 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212485/xunit-runner-visualstudio-not-working-on-visual-studio-2013-update-4)

So there's a lot going round, none of it helped ...

**Update**

I can't get NUnit to work either, won't show up in test explorer as well.

**Update 2**

I wiped my project and recreated the projects like so:

[image]

Then I copied my original code and added all necessary references, no difference.

Comment: Do you have the "testRunner", and in dependencies,  "dotnet-test-xunit" set in your project.json file ?

Comment: What is `testrunner` and `dotnet-test-xunit` cannot be found anywhere in my solution folder structure.

Comment: What is the exact project type you use? .NET Core, or not? It is not an easy setup at this moment, due to the complexity of project types, so you must make it very clear what you are doing.

Comment: 4.6.1, updated.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43158783/5112433)? Does Resharper discover those tests?

Comment: if you're using Nunit you have to add the attribute [TestFixture] to your test class and [TestCase] to your test methods - i don't know the equivalent in xUnit but i'll bet you'll have to do something similar otherwise it won't pick up your tests

Comment: You are definitely using 4.6.1? When creating a new project in VS2017 (New Project->Templates->Visual C#) you selected .NET Standard and not .NET Core (it will still say .NET Framework x.y.z up the top, even though a Core project is created)? I ask, as I have to run _dotnet restore_ to get my xUnit tests to show at present.

Comment: @Ayb4btu I'll check asap. Might be it.

Comment: @Ayb4btu See update 2, everything seems to have been created as it should afaik.

Comment: @Spikee can you make your project available somewhere, and I'll attempt to get it running. This will help see if it is a problem with visual studio or with the solution.

Comment: @Ayb4btu https://github.com/KristofBD/Aetheria.git - switch to the `dev/game-loop` branch.

Comment: Did you try clearing cache as posted here? https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#run-tests-visualstudio

Comment: @brijber I'll check when able :P.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After trawling the internet, it appears that targeting *NETStandard.Library* can't be used for test projects...

These were the links I got information from:

- [Unit Tests not discovered in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861930/unit-tests-not-discovered-in-visual-studio-2017)
- [Visual Studio 2017 RC does not detect nunit tests](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/305)
- [running xunit tests included in a .NET Standard 1.6 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684047/running-xunit-tests-included-in-a-net-standard-1-6-library)

What can be done is have the project you want to test use *NETStandard.Library* and have your test project target *Microsoft.NETCore.App*. Your test project can then reference the project to test and the tests will run.

The .csproj for your test project will look something like this (versions might change):

```
<PropertyGroup>    
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The project to test would be this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

<strike>Lately I've had to run *dotnet restore* on the solution to get the tests to run, so you may need to do the same.</strike> Turns out .NET Core SDK 1.0.1 was being targeted instead of 1.0.4 (I didn't have the x86 version installed).

Comment: That helped getting it working, thanks for the effort!

Comment: so we were doing this in prod - but then we started testing a file that uses "System.Windows.Forms" and our .netCore2.1 TESTAPP blew up (can't load "System.Windows.Forms" from another assembly)

Comment: @Poat, I suspect that it is because winforms is not supported by .NET Core 2. Try using [.NET Core 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) (it is only in preview at the moment though). If you still have issues, I would recommend posting a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu Tests -> Test Settings -> Default process architecture -> change it according to the platform target.